# CSS rules not applied correctly/completely

Tags: css, ipad, homescreen

I'm having a really bizarre problem with a homescreen html app on an ipad.  It's a rather complex single-page app, which is also loaded for offline use with the cache.manifest.

I have three css files: one global plus one for each portrait and landscape, which are loaded using media queries. The media queries use screen width - to ensure they work correctly with other devices. CSS are loaded like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ebot.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 820px)" type="text/css" href="css/ebot-ls.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 819px)" type="text/css" href="css/ebot-ss.css"/>
```

On a high level, the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="screen1" class="fullscreen">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="screen2" class="fullscreen hidden">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="screen3" class="fullscreen hidden">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Class `.hidden` is defined as `.hidden { display: none; }`

Naturally, within each of the fullscreen divs, there are lots of other elements.  When the app starts, `screen1` is visible and then through user interaction, it's replaced by either `screen2` or `screen3`.

Now, when I start the app with ipad being in portrait mode, everything works perfectly fine.  If I then rotate it into landscape, everything works fine - with new style rules applied correctly.

When I start the app with the ipad in landscape mode, I get a really messed up screen with `screen1` visible in full screen, as it's supposed to be.  Yet, as it has transparent background, I can see behind its elements individual child elements of both screen2 and screen3, but without any of their css classes applied to them at all.  In addition, the elements on the visible screen1 also seem to have only some CSS rules applied to them (e.g. borders are in place, but fonts are not).

If I rotate the ipad into portrait mode and then back to landscape, everything fixes itself.

I attached the ipad to my mac to debug it from Safari.  In the debugger, when I inspect the elements, I can see the styles being applied correctly, so by all rules none of the "background nonsense" should be visible. If in the inspector in Safari I uncheck rule `display: none` and then check it again, then everything fixes itself.

Overall it feels/looks like CSS are only applied partially on the first load - and only after the page refresh/repaint/re-something are they applied correctly.

This makes the app utterly unusable.  I can't expect my users to rotate the device and then rotate it back before using the app.

What can I try doing to solve this problem?

Comment: This is a total shot in the dark, but try changing the `.hidden` class to use `display: none` in place of `visibility: none` and see what happens, if you haven't already.

Comment: @Jmh2013 Sorry, I really do need more sleep.  It's already that.

Comment: That was my only guess..unfortunately I have no idea what the issue might be. Hah lack of sleep is a requirement for a developer!

Comment: @Jmh2013 _lack of sleep is a requirement for a developer_ heh, add three small children to the equation and a second full-time job

Comment: do you have a meta tag for the viewport in your header?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried orientation media queries?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ebot.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 820px) and (orientation:landscape)" type="text/css" href="css/ebot-ls.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 819px) and (orientation:portrait)" type="text/css" href="css/ebot-ss.css"/>
```

[Check the documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation) for alternatives that may help.

Also, this meta tag has served me well in the past with iPad issues such as these

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0">
```

[Some documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#viewport-meta) on the viewport meta tag to clear any doubts

**EDIT:** [Others have stumbled upon this](https://github.com/sergiolopes/ios-zoom-bug-fix)

Comment: Orientation is not the same as width. On iPhones, even in the landscape mode, I need to use the small screen version of classes.  In addition, this does absolutely nothing to address the actual problem of styles not being applied correctly.  The media queries already work as needed.

Comment: @AleksG I know it's not the same, I've updated my answer to include your widths. 
I did solve similar issues with the viewport meta tag I mentioned.

In the CSS itself I used `(max-aspect-ratio: 13/9)` in the past and it did the job.

I'm sorry if I can't be of any more help.